# String changes after NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsurlconnection

This is part of my ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    NSString *idUser;
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSMutableData *responseDataPersonal;
}
```

And this is my .m:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if (URLtype == 1)
        responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    else if (URLtype = 3)
        responseDataPersonal = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (URLtype == 1)
        [responseData appendData:data];
    else if (URLtype == 2)
        [responseDataPersonal appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    ...
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
     if(URLtype == 1) 
     {
        URLtype = 2;
        // responseData contains this line of text: "true;1234567"
        NSString *txt = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];

            // idUser is set to 1234567
            NSArray *txtString = [txt componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];
            idUser = [txtString objectAtIndex: 1];

            // This NSLog PERFECTLY logs 1234567
            NSLog(@"%@",idUser);


            NSString *post = @"task=something";
            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
            [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.site.com/script.php"]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        }
    }


    else if (URLtype == 2)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ blabla", idUser);
    }
}
```

I want the NSLog in at the end of the code to work, but it keeps giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes on that line.
There is definitly something very weird going on cause if I change that NSLog line to:

```
 NSString *idUser2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", idUser];
    NSLog(@"%@ BLA", idUser2);
```

.. it crashes sometime OR logs different messages every time! Here are some examples:

```
<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x777df70> BLA
```

or

```
HTTP connection to www.site.com:80 BLA
```

or

```
HTTPHeaderDict 0x856d870 [0x856d878]> { <CFBasicHash 0x855a2a0 [0x1b3b4d8]>{type = immutable dict, count = 5,
entries =>
    1 : Content-Length = <CFString 0x85723d0 [0x1b3b4d8]>{contents = "36"}
    3 : Accept-Encoding = <CFString 0x25b48f8 [0x1b3b4d8]>{contents = "gzip, deflate"}
    4 : Content-Type = <CFString 0x3e420 [0x1b3b4d8]>{contents = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    5 : Accept-Language = <CFString 0x8572a00 [0x1b3b4d8]>{contents = "en-us"}
    6 : Accept = <CFString 0x25b4308 [0x1b3b4d8]>{contents = "*/*"}
}
 } BLA
```

Lately it prefers crashing.. at the `NSString *idUser2 line.`

What am I doing wrong? :/
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a:

```
idUser = nil;
```

at the top of your "`connectionDidFinishLoading`" method.  My guess is that "`idUser`" has not necessarily been set and instead is some garbage or released value by the time it gets to that NSLog line.

Comment: Ok it won't crash anymore now, but it returns null on the NSLog now. How would I fix that?

Comment: Step through the Xcode debugger and see what happens when your program arrives (*if it arrives*) at the "`idUser = [txtString objectAtIndex: 1];`" line.

Comment: It successfully creates the txtString Array of the items 'true' and '1234567'. Then idUser is a string "1234567" and contains an NSObjects, isa, and ends with [0] = (Class) <error: unknown Class>.

Comment: Your `idUser` contains a string now.  So, is there a problem?

Comment: Yes there is, since it doesn't contain that string anymore at the second NSLog. So something happens with it after the second NSURLconnection is called..

Comment: Your second NSLog doesn't get called until the next time you go through "`connectionDidFinishLoading`" because the second NSLog is behind an "`else`" case. If you want to *store* "`idUser`" between calls to "`connectionDidFinishLoading`", you need to retain "`idUser`" (via something like "`idUser = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [txtString objectAtIndex: 1]];`".

Comment: Damn, that did the trick. I didn't realize that assigning a value from an array would be retained.. Thanks, putting it into a string solved it!

Comment: wouldn't be retained*

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

NSString * theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but Michael had the answer! :)

Comment: but I will +1 your answer @user2826529, because you had the right idea!